# Qt | creating a dynamic object in a customized scene

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qgraphicsscene

Good day to all!
I would like to learn from the respected community how it is possible using Qt Designer to create a simple GUI that performs what is shown in the attached image. Namely: after a single click of the LMB, a marker is placed at the place of the click, indicating the beginning of the polygon, and a temporary polygon of the desired type (but of different sizes) begins to follow the mouse cursor until we click on the LMB again, after which the final polygon will be built from the point of the first click of the LMB to the point of the second click. Such a ready-made polygon will have to be stored somewhere in memory for further work with it.
As a polygon here, I show a complex sector built on some calculated points, but as a simple example, you can take a straight line - I don't think that the essence of the program changes much.
I have already looked at many examples of different implementations of different things on QGraphicsScene, but I could not figure out exactly how to create an object in the way I needed. That is, I know that we need a separate class describing the polygon and calculating the coordinates of which it consists, but I don't quite understand how to implement the dynamics - with each mousemoveivent, delete the temporary polygon and draw a new one for the new coordinates, or how?
P.S. If it won't be so difficult, could someone also show how to implement what was conceived through the redefined paintScene class, replacing the standard QGraphicsScene class and inheriting from it? I am faced with the fact that when creating a custom class of the scene object, clicking on the objects attached to it is ignored by the program, and instead of, for example, dragging an object on the scene when clicking on it, the mousePressEvent of the scene, not the object, is triggered, and I do not understand what the problem is.
P.P.S. I apologize for my English and thank everyone for any help!
[image]

Comment: Basically you need to create a custom class that inherits `QGraphicsObject`, representing your shape and that build it from your two points. Then link the click and move mouse events in `QGraphicsView` in order to create the object and set the first point with the first click, then set the second point with the mouse move event, and then create the definitive shape with the second mouse click (I'll add a right-mouse click event for cancel the operation)

Comment: @Jepessen, thank you for your reply!
But tell me, please, how exactly should the rebuilding of the polygon be implemented by moving the mouse? Should I delete the polygon object and recreate it every time the mouse moves from MainWindow::mouseMoveEvent, or should I somehow pass the new two points to the polygon class, and somehow initiate a change in the coordinates of the polygon points there?

Comment: You need to see the documentation for `QGraphicsItem`. Basically you need to override some protected methods, like `boundingRect` and `paint` methods, drawing the shape according to mouse positions. Then add two private members, like `_startPoint` and `_endPoint`, and then se the value of `_startPoint` with your first mouse click, and the other point when you move the mouse, overriding `mousePressEvent` and `mouseMoveEvent`. Check some tutorial about how to create custom QGraphicsItem, it's simpler than you think if you read a bit of documentation.

Comment: @RomanZuev, have you implemented the solution? Could you share it in the answers?